# get list of objects with uniques prv_codigo and adding string properties of duplicates

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a list from a database like this:

```
results: any[] = [
{
prv_codigo: 1,
agrupaciones:'apple',
icon:'fruit'
},
{
prv_codigo: 1,
agrupaciones:'pinia',
icon:'tropical_fruit'
},
{
prv_codigo: 1,
agrupaciones:'melon',
icon:'fruit'
},
{
prv_codigo: 1,
agrupaciones:'banana',
icon:'tropical_fruit'
},
{
prv_codigo: 2,
agrupaciones:'apple',
icon:'fruit'
},
]
```

What I need is to reduce this array resulting like this, I mean grouping the property 'agrupaciones' into one string with commas and picking up the first icon it encounters in the original array and making a unique object:

```
newResults: any[] = [
{
prv_codigo: 1,
agrupaciones:'apple,pinia,melon,banana',
icon:'fruit'
},
{
prv_codigo: 2,
agrupaciones:'apple',
icon:'fruit'
},
]
```

Comment: if you are using typescript then pls update your question tags. This is invalid in regular js `results: any[] = [`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be looping through `map` and creating a new array by checking `prv_codigo` property like :

```
const newArr = [];
results.map(result => {
  let newArrElm = newArr.filter(elm => elm.prv_codigo == result.prv_codigo);
  if (newArrElm.length == 1){
    newArrElm[0].agrupaciones += "," + result.agrupaciones;
  } else {
    newArr.push(result);
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```